# php mysql username variable contains two values

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if we could have one variable equals two string values? I made a login form which is not required username, only requires password. if the password matches, then it displays the the right person name. **I fully understand this is not a right way or a secure way to do login form, but this form will only internally for 5 people use.**

inside the php file, I set the `$username = "PersonName";` the form only requires password,
if the password is correct, this person could login and the name  "PersonName1" on the page. I use mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password_encrypt '");
```

If I want to add another `PersonName2` can I have `$username="PersonName1" || $username = "PersonName2";`

or if someone could give me some ideas? Many thanks

Comment: What if 100 users have same password?

Comment: He said the login form will only be used by 5 people. It's still a horrible way to do it, though.

Comment: [Bobby Tables would have a field day on your site](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @hjpotter92 this doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I thought Bobby was then kicked from school.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Juampi explained it better. :/ I just pasted from question ^_^

Comment: @hjpotter92 I left reading the question from here *if the password matches, then it displays the the right person name*

Comment: no make any sense ....

Comment: consider this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1894905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `OR` operand in your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR username='$username2') AND password='$password_encrypt '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username IN ('$username', '$username2')
    AND password='$password_encrypt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to check for `X OR Y` in mysql, just make sure you use parenthesis to separate your conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$firstName' || username='$secondName') AND password='$password_encrypt '
```

Answer (score 0):

OR is available to use in MYSQL

```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR username='$username2') AND password='$password_encrypt '
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't require a username then in the SQL query just search for a matching password, then using PHP you can

```
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ /* check for a good username?? */ }
```

Also, mysql_* has been deprecated, research MySQLi or PDO for best practices.